# What's the best way to save online Image in sqflite, flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, sqflite

I'm using sqflite to create my SQL database and save the data I receive from the RESTful API locally. I get the image link from the API but I have no idea how to store it. should I heard I can use BLOB (Uint8List) and cached_network_image. which of these two (or another way!) would u suggest and how to do it exactly?

I tried to save the Image link as String, but it did not satisfy my needs because I need to load my images once and load them locally next times.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I searched on this topic, storing the image as a file on the device and as a string with the filename in the db was the proposed solution